# Getting useful information about event attendees

Tags: php, events, facebook-graph-api

We have a Facebook event with an associated web site. On the web site we would like to be able to show interesting information about the attendees. I am find this remarkably hard to do. There does not seem to be a simple means of returning the number of attendees, nor does it seem practical to get, say, the most recent 25 users who say they are coming. All that I have discovered so far is the Graph API for listing attendees is broken (it won't return more than 999), the 'since' parameter appears to be ignored for the 'attending' function and trying to get just the most recent 25 would mean wading through potentially thousands of entries (if the API did return the correct number) - assuming that the most recent are at the end.

Am I completely mistaken (I would like to be!) or is this API just not suitable for this seemingly mundane task? (Ideally I am looking to do this with PHP but other working solutions would be considered.)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is using a [FQL Multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) against the 'event' table to get **hopefully** more than 999 attendees and for the detailed information about them you can insert a query against the user id, which you get from the table 'event_member'. But you'll only be able to see the users with a privacy setting that allows everyone to see their rsvp status.

For the number of real attendees you're in bad luck, there's no field for that. All you can do for that is push the event_members into an array with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (set assoc to true) and then count() it.

For the latest attendees...yeah propably just check the end of the list - fastest I can come up with would be to take the count - 25 and start your list from there then.